# How can I avoid not-exhaustive-match warnings with Scala RegexParsers

Tags: regex, scala

I have something like this:

```
  def numberBrace: Parser[Double] = "{" ~ number ~ "}" ^^ {
    case "{" ~ num ~ "}" => num
    case _               => 0.0
  }
```

This compiles cleanly, but if I didn't have the "case _" line there I get a "match may not be exhaustive" warning on compile.

I've got a lot of these clause-parsers, so these little extra case _ additions litter my code.  Are they really needed here, and if not, how can I avoid them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem goes away if you use RegexParsers' ~> and <~ operators. a ~> b matches but doesn't capture a, then matches but does capture b.  b <~ c matches/captures b and matches/doesn't-capture c.  So the original question can be accomplished like this:

```
  def numberBrace: Parser[Double] = "{" ~> number <~ "}" ^^ { num => num }
```

This matches but ignores the braces but captures the number, which is simply returned in the ^^ clause.  Much cleaner!